# Setting the certificate used by a Java SSL ServerSocket

Tags: java, ssl

I want to open a secure listening socket in a Java server application. I know that the recommended way to do that is to just do this:

```
SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
ServerSocket ss = ssf.createServerSocket(443);
```

But this requires to pass the certificate of the server to the JVM when launching java. Because this would make some things in deployment more complicated for me, I would prefer to load the certificate at runtime.

So I have a key file and a password and I want a server socket. How do I get there? Well, I read the documentation and the only way I could find is this:

```
// these are my parameters for SSL encryption
char[] keyPassword =  "P@ssw0rd!".toCharArray();
FileInputStream keyFile = new FileInputStream("ssl.key"); 

// init keystore
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
keyStore.load(keyFile, keyPassword);
// init KeyManagerFactory
KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, keyPassword);
// init KeyManager
KeyManager keyManagers[] = keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();
// init the SSL context
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getDefault();
sslContext.init(keyManagers, null, new SecureRandom());
// get the socket factory
SSLServerSocketFactory socketFactory = sslContext.getServerSocketFactory();

// and finally, get the socket
ServerSocket serverSocket = socketFactory.createServerSocket(443);
```

And that doesn't even have any error handling. Is it really that complicated? Isn't there an easier way to do it?

Comment: This question is very much about the problem of setting the certificate. Your title didn't highlight that (and the one answer so far seems to have missed that point), so i have taken the liberty of changing it. Please do improve the title further if you like.

Comment: I think the code you've come up with so far is (a) horrific and (b) nonetheless very likely to be the 'right' way to do this. Java isn't always excessively verbose, but when it is, it is really, really excessively verbose.

Comment: If you think that's complicated, try doing it with NIO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But this requires to pass the certificate of the server to the JVM when launching java.

No it doesn't. Just set these system properties before you create the `SSLServerSocket:`

```
javax.net.ssl.keyStore ssl.key
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword P@ssw0rd!
```

You can do that with `System.setProperties()` *or* on the command line.

Comment: This isn't recommanded. Don't rely on system properties for anything :/ You might not be able to create concurrent sockets with a different certificate each. I personally followed https://gpotter2.github.io/tutos/en/sslsockets

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the code, you can see why it's necessarily complicated.  This code decouples the implementation of the SSL protocol from:

- the source of your key material (`KeyStore`)
- certificate algorithm choice and key management (`KeyManager`)
- management of peer trust rules (`TrustManager`) - not used here
- secure random algorithm (`SecureRandom`)
- NIO or socket implementation (`SSLServerSocketFactory`) - could use `SSLEngine` for NIO

Consider what your own implementation would look like if you were trying to reach the same goals!

Comment: But I am using the default for all of that. There should be a more straight-forward way.

Comment: @Philipp There is no default keystore.

Answer (score 1):

Use this.

```
public class KeyMaster
{
     public static SSLSocketFactory getSSLSocketFactory(KeyStore trustKey, String sslAlgorithm)
{
    try
    {
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init(trustKey);

        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance(sslAlgorithm);//"SSL" "TLS"
        context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        return context.getSocketFactory();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Assistance.log("Err: getSSLSocketFactory(), ");
    }

    return null;
}

public static SSLServerSocketFactory getSSLServerSocketFactory(KeyStore trustKey, String sslAlgorithm)
{
    try
    {
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init(trustKey);

        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance(sslAlgorithm);//"SSL" "TLS"
        context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        return context.getServerSocketFactory();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Assistance.log("Err: getSSLSocketFactory(), ");
    }

    return null;
}

public static SSLServerSocket getSSLServerSocket(SSLServerSocketFactory socketFactory, int port)
{
    try
    {
        return (SSLServerSocket) socketFactory.createServerSocket(port);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {Assistance.log("Err: getSSLSocket(), ");}

    return null;
}

public static KeyStore getFromPath(String path, String algorithm, String filePassword)//PKSC12
{
    try
    {
        File f = new File(path);

        if(!f.exists())
            throw new RuntimeException("Err: File not found.");

        FileInputStream keyFile = new FileInputStream(f);
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(algorithm);
        keystore.load(keyFile, filePassword.toCharArray());
        keyFile.close();

        return keystore;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Assistance.log("Err: getFromPath(), " + e.toString());
    }

    return null;
}
```

and in main.

```
 KeyStore key = KeyMaster.getFromPath(".\\cssl.pfx", "PKCS12", "123");
        SSLServerSocketFactory fac = KeyMaster.getSSLServerSocketFactory(key, "TLS");
        listener = KeyMaster.getSSLServerSocket(fac, 49015);
```